# Django ALLOWED_HOSTS equivalent for banned host?

Tags: django

In Django 1.5 you can set allowed hosts:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '.example.com',   # Allow domain and subdomains
    '.example.com.',  # Also allow FQDN and subdomains
]
```

Is there an equivalent for banned hosts? i.e. I provide a list of IP's to just automatically reject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass through a middleware, as the documentation says:

> A value of '*' will match anything; in this case you are responsible to provide your own validation of the Host header (perhaps in a middleware; if so this middleware must be listed first in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES).

See [Django settings documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/).

Answer (score 1):

No there is no equivanlent in settings for that purpose.

You can create your own middlewares: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/725/ http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/744/

Or use some ready made package: https://bitbucket.org/codekoala/django-tracking