# How to allow special IP or host access /admin page with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, host

If Django, we can use `ALLOWED_HOSTS = []` in the `settings.py` file.

How to do it with Rails?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020900/django-allowed-hosts-equivalent-for-banned-host

Comment: you can probably add a `before_filter` method and check `request.remote_ip` against the list of allowed ip addresses

Comment: Can't we use `middleware` configs for this.? or before_filter in application controller to check special IPs.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try

```
def local_allow_ip_ranges
    %w{
      127.0.0.1
      12.123.1.123
      192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0
    }
  end
```

Now below This is the method that checks if the given IP is in the above list

```
def is_local(ip)
    require 'ipaddr'
    ip = IPAddr.new(ip)
    local_allow_ip_ranges.any? {|range| IPAddr.new(range).include?(ip) }
  end
```